# I have the following f(n)<=g(n) .. does this gives me that also sum(f(n)) <= sum(g(n)) (the sum is from 1 to infinity)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

functiosn f and g accepts natural numbers like this : `f,g :N->R+`
I have the following if there is a constant `c>0` and m>0 that for every `n > m` we get:

```
f(n) <= c* g(n)
(f(n)=O(g(n))
```

does this gives me that also:

```
sum(f(n)) <= C*sum(g(n))   %the sum is from 1 to n 
sum(f(n))=O(C*sum(g(n)) )
```

I think this is wrong and I am trieng to find an example that will contradict to this (also if this statement is wrong if we will replace the two sides will it stay wrong?. Any help or hint will be very apprciated.

Answer (score 2):

No, this statement is not true.

Consider the following:

```
f(n) = n = 1 : 1
       n > 1 : 0

g(n) = n = 1 : 0
       n > 1 : 0
```

For any n > 1:

```
f(n) <= c*g(n)
```

And:

```
sum(f(n)) = 1
sum(g(n)) = 0
```

It's clear that `sum(f(n))` is actually larger than `sum(g(n))`

Comment: but i need to prove this that i can find a c constant and m that will make the statment true :\ so i don't think it has to work for every m in this case you chose m=5

Comment: @james I can't guess what *you need to prove*, I just answered your question.

Comment: Just for fun changed the example. Now it's counter example to **any m** you choose.

Comment: can you just explain what do you mean in this line ? g(n) = n = 1 : 0

Comment: It means that value of g at n=1 equals to 0